# I'm having date conversion problems with the 3rd column in the script below

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Select c1.CDS_Date, c2.CDS_Date, Dateadd(day, -1 , c2.CDS_Date) 
from cte as c1 left join 
     cte as c2  
     on c1.[Local Patient Identifier] = c2.[Local Patient Identifier] and 
        c1.JoinKey = c2.JoinKey - 1
```

Can I get come help please?

I got no issues with `c1.CDS_Date` and `c2.CDS_Date`.

I receive the following error message as soon as I include the 3rd column:

```
(24 rows affected)
Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 50
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an --out-of-range value.
```

Comment: Tag the dbms you'er using. When it comes to date/time many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.

Comment: What type is your `c2.CDS_Date` - I would guess that not date, but varchar?

Comment: Please order by CDS_Date and check if any date in table is less than 1753 .... min date in sql. Maybe it will help. Maybe it is very close to min date in sql so there is the error.

Comment: @Arkadiusz - I think you mean 1753.

Comment: Yes Damien thank you

Answer (score 1):

That is because your `CDS_Date` is not of `date`/`datetime` type but is a string.

Here is an example:

```
declare @t table (CDS_Date varchar(100));
insert into @t values ('28/10/2017');

set language British;
select CDS_Date, dateadd(day, -1, CDS_Date) as dt
from @t;
-------
--CDS_Date  dt
--28/10/2017    2017-10-27 00:00:00.000


set language us_english;
select CDS_Date, dateadd(day, -1, CDS_Date) as dt
from @t;

--Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 40
--The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
```

This example shows you that not every string can be converted to `date` EVEN IF it seems to you that it represents a valid data. This is because server expects a date that you pass as a string to be in the certain format that depends on session language.

To be independent of session language you shoud pass your date string using convert function and specifying the format of your date.

In my example I can fix the issue converting to `date` with `style 103`:

```
select CDS_Date, dateadd(day, -1, convert(date, CDS_Date, 103)) as dt
from @t;
----
--CDS_Date  dt
--28/10/2017    2017-10-27
```

Now it gives me the correct result in both languages just because it knows that my input strings are of `103 format`, i.e. `dd/mm/yyyy`